# Is the empty set necessarily part of any collection of subsets of a set $S$?

Tags: general-topology

My question is tied to the presented proof for the "only if" of the claim:

> *A collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of a set $S$ is a basis for some topology $\tau$ on $S$* iff
> i.) $S$ is the union of all sets in $\mathcal{B}$ and
> ii.) given any two sets $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and a point $p \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then there is a set $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $p \in B \subset B_1 \cap B_2$

in the book *An Introduction to Manifolds* by Loring (pp.322)

Namely, the author starts by defining $\tau$ to be the collection of all sets that are unions of sets in $\mathcal{B}$. Then the author claims:

> Then the empty set $\varnothing$ and $S$ are in $\tau$ and $\tau$ is clearly closed under arbitrary union.

My question is is that why is $\varnothing$ necessarily in $\tau$? I don't see how the properties i.) and ii.) immediately imply why $\varnothing \in \mathcal{B}$

Comment: For i: $\forall A, A \cup \emptyset = A$. For ii take $B_1=B_2=B=\emptyset$.

Comment: Empty set is in $\tau$ because it is an *empty* union, i.e. the union of *none* sets in $\mathcal B$.

Comment: The properties don't have anything (much) to do with it.  But the definition that $\tau$ is a collection of *all* unions has everything to do with it.  The *empty* union of sets is always the empty set.  Another way of thinking of this (albeit heavy an the notation) is that if $\mathscr B = \{B_1,B_2,B_3,......\}$ then *a* union is defined as: Let $C\subset \mathscr B$, Then $\bigcup_{B_i\in C} B_i$ is a union.  As $\emptyset\subset \mathscr B$ then $\bigcup_{B_i\in \emptyset}B_i = \emptyset$ is a perfectly well defined union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All sets that are unions of sets in $\mathcal B$" means "all sets of the form $\bigcup\mathcal A$ where $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal B$."
Now $\varnothing\subseteq\mathcal B$, and if $\mathcal A=\varnothing$ then $\bigcup\mathcal A=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

"the author starts by defining τ to be the collection of all sets that are unions of sets in B. "

The way to define a set that is a union of sets in $\mathscr B$ is to find some collection of sets in $B$ and ... union them.  Now the emptyset qualifies as a collection of sets-- an *empty* collection of sets.

This notation will make any novice screaming to the hills but

$\mathscr B = \{B_\alpha\}$

$\tau = \{\bigcup_{\text{some form of indexing}} B_i\}=$

$\{\bigcup_{B_i\in C}B_i|$ where $C$ is some subset of $\mathscr B\}$

$\{\bigcup_{B_i\in C}B_i| C\in \mathscr P(\mathscr B)\}$

Now as $\emptyset \subset \mathscr B$ we have that $\bigcup_{B_i\in \emptyset}B_i\in \tau$.

And $\bigcup_{B_i\in \emptyset}B_i = \emptyset$.